# Should I list my work as a frequent journal reviewer as a volunteer work in LinkedIn?

Tags: journals, peer-review, cv, social-media

I am a frequent reviewer for a particular (computer science) journal, and I wonder if the review work I do counts as a "volunteer" work?

I do already list this work in my CV under (PROFESSIONAL ACTIVITIES) section. Should I also add it to my LinkedIn profile under (volunteer experience) section?

Comment: My impression is that LinkedIn is not widely used by academics, and as such, there may not be clear conventions or expectations among academics as to how to fit such things into LinkedIn sections.

Comment: I've seen people do it.  However, we expect anyone who has published to review some papers.  There is no prestige in that, especially when the invitation process is mostly automated.  There are some publishers or journals who award 'best reviewer for the year' type recognition.  That is better and says that you take your job seriously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the academic value of posts on LinkedIn?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/71807/what-is-the-academic-value-of-posts-on-linkedin)

Comment: I suggest this be closed as off-topic or duplicate because the linked question indicates academics don't use LinkedIn for academic purposes.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should take advantage of being a peer reviewer. You can add it to your LinkedIn account, and create a profile on Publons and ReviewerCredits to be registered as a peer reviewer.